# Converting datetime format got this issue 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime' in DRF

Tags: python, django, string, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a date time value November 10, 2021 which is to be converted into Django default datetime. I tried but got this error.

I have a date value which I got from list of dictionaries like this which is a datetime field.

```
created_at = data[0]['created_at']
print(created_at)
```

The print I got is like `June 12, 2021`

Now I tried this.

```
c = created_at.strftime(('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
print(created_at)
print(c)
```

When I print c, I got the above error. I know created_at object doesnt have strftime function but how can this conversion be done??

Comment: The date you're getting from your dictionary is a string. That string can't be used as an object. Convert that string in to a datetime object then you can apply `strftime` to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime
This should help. Pass your string through strptime; then format however you wish. Or format it whilst parsing.